# Differential equations: error on founding solution

Tags: differential

I have to found the solution of this differential equation: y'=-2-y^2, it look simple but I didn't think so. After solving the differential eqaution I have to plot the solution.

What I do:

function DY=solution(t,y)

DY=$-2-y^2$;

end

$[t,y]=ode45(@solution, [0, 4], 0)$; %% I have this message

Warning: Failure at $t=1.110695e+00$.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the
smallest value allowed $(3.552714e-15)$ at time $t$.

> In $ode45$ at $309$

%% $[t,y]=ode45(@solution, [0, 4], 0)$ I get an array of numerical solution

%% in both cases the solution plotted give something not good

plot$(t,y)$[[solution figure][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCNg8.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCNg8.jpg)

Comment: Everything works fine here and the warning is appropriate since the solution does explode in finite time. Furthermore, for the initial condition y(0)=0 the time of explosion is t=pi/(2sqrt(2))=1.11072..., in accordance with the warning message.

Comment: Please try to learn and use formatting next time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Notice, we have $$y'=-2-y^2$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-(2+y^2)$$ $$\frac{dy}{2+y^2}=-dt$$ integrating both the sides, we get $$\int \frac{dy}{2+y^2}=-\int dt$$ 
 $$\int \frac{dy}{(\sqrt2)^2+y^2}=-\int dt$$ 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt 2}\right)=-t+c$$

Can you simplify further?

Comment: Could someone please tell what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct, indeed. What I suppose is that someone does not understand that the problem happens if $t=something$.

Comment: No, kindly recheck the derivative it's $y'=-2-y^2$.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Sorry I erred seeing and so cancelled my comment

Comment: At the very least, this lacks an explanation of the explosion of the solution witnessed by the OP (who, as happens on the site, seems to be happy with an answer to a different question than the one they asked).

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But perhaps it could help him.

Answer (score 0):

Using Matlab? Before attempting numerical solution, first attempt a symbolic closed form solution.

Try the $t$ interval [0,1.1] because of vertical asymptote for  $ \tan$ function.

Answer (score -2):

It work good, so now how solve this problem whene I wnat to plot the solution on a bigger interval conataining O for example [-5,5]?

Comment: ?? Do you realize that the solution is NOT defined on the whole interval [-5,5]?

Comment: I know, but the problem that I found some figure of the solution of this differential equation in some courses, how did they do it?

Comment: They plotted the solution on its interval of definition, probably.